# How To Transverse/Manipulate the DOM in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild, elementref

I am looking for how to access a DOM element in A4.

I am having a hard time trying to wrap my head around this...  I've been reading about ElementRef, ViewChild, etc... but I still don't fully understand how to transverse the DOM elements in Angular 4.  For example what would this jQuery statement be in A4?

```
$('events > ion-content > div.scroll-content > ion-grid:nth-child(1)').css({blah blah});
```

Like:

```
ElementRef.nativeElement - events > ion-content > div.scroll-content > ion-grid:nth-child(1)
```

How do I access that element in the fashion above - without adding any ids, classes, or #template tags?  In certain situations I cannot access the html so I would like to know how to do this without the  use of jQuery since it's frowned upon with Angular :[

Comment: why do you need to do that? That's *probably* the question you want to ask. I admit that this is usually an annoying question to ask, but quite often when making the transition between jQuery and Angular-esque frameworks we don't explicitly need to do complex DOM element selection/manipulation. Don't be too descriptive, just say 'Im trying to do drag/drop etc'

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Well in one case that I ran into this need was when I was trying to add a search bar into the ionic generated radio alert.  I currently can use jQuery to append the search bar in, but as noted everywhere jQ is not A4 appropriate. Other times tracking elements height,scroll positions, etc.

Comment: I am just looking for how to access the element - once there I can most likely figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this 
`<ion-grid [class.add-this-class]="whenThisState === true"></ion-grid>` ?
or `ngClass` syntax if you fancy that.

Or do you want to get that element from a parent component or some other component ?

-EDIT-

If you cannot go to the angular template and do some binding there as I mentioned before, then basically you have 2 options Vanilla JS: 
`private theElementYouAreLookingFor: HTMLElement`

In `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle try to fetch it with JS and store it `this.theElementYouAreLookingFor` or

with by using the new Angular way 
`@ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;`
`constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}`
and in `ngAfterViewInit()` `this.el.nativeElement();`

or by using `Observables` something like this:
`const clickEl = document.querySelector('#my-button');

const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(clickEl, 'click');`

and then subscribe

`click$.subscribe(...)`

Comment: Don't have access to the html element in this case.

Comment: I will post another answer based on your feedback @RooksStrife, but can you please elaborate more how do you mean you don't have access to the angular template ? Is it inside an iframe ?